# HTTP GET method parameter format for object

Tags: servicestack

Can I set my request object by http parameters with GET method, if request contains not primitive object. I can do it for POST method with json, but does exist some GET alternative?

```
[DataContract]
[RestService("/foo")]    
public class FooRequest  
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Color1 { get; set; }


    [DataMember]
    public FooDto Dto { get; set; }

}

public class FooDto
{
    public string Color2 { get; set;}
}
```

In this example Color1 is set but how can I set Dto.color2?

```
http://server/fooservice/servicestack/foo?Color1=blue&Dto.Color2=red
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net), you can set complex type properties on a QueryString by using the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format). See this earlier [answer for an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13277036/85785).

So to set the Complex Type **Dto** property your queryString would look like:

```
http://server/fooservice/servicestack/foo?Color1=blue&Dto={Color2:red}
```